# Most performant way to parse an Inputstream

Tags: java, performance, parsing, inputstream, bufferedreader

I would like to find the fastest way to parse an inputstream. The inputstream is dynamic and the first lines contain all the info to parse the data.
eg:

```
key,val
INTEGER,INTEGER
1,5
2,5
```

In order to do the parsing I am currently using a BufferedReader. I read line by line, split on , (which is the separator) and then parse to the type given at the beginning. eg:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 
// ...
String line = reader.readLine();
String[] line = StringUtils.split(stringToSplit, ',');
Integer.parse(line[0]);
```

I was wondering what is the performance impact of doing that, and what I could do to improve the performance ? Should I use byte[] ? Thanks !

Comment: This is [Premature Optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/989).  The parsing overhead will be minimal.  Don't overthink this unless you can prove there's a bottleneck.

Comment: You can read miillions of lines per second with `BufferedReader`. That's fast enough.